# koa-router has no functions

Tags: node.js, koa, koa-router

I tried to import the koa-router into my nodejs app like this:

[image]

but when checking the code completion, there is no `get` method to be found. Or any other method.

I installed it using `npm install koa-router` but apparently something is not working.

Can someone help me?

Comment: According to the documentation, `router` is a class that needs to be instantiated. [Read the docs](https://github.com/koajs/router/blob/HEAD/API.md), don't try to guess how the library works.

Answer (score 1):

`koa-router` is now `@koa/router`. In the documentation you should find this:

> This module is forked from the original koa-router due to its lack of activity.

So your code should look like this:

```js
const Koa = require('koa');
const Router = require('@koa/router');

const app = new Koa();
const router = new Router();

router.get('/', (ctx, next) => {
  // ctx.router available
});
```

This way I guess, your code completion should work. Can you confirm this?

Comment: No it is not working for me!